# How to create array mask by comparing to a string?

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am trying to use numpy's array comparison to create a mask if a value is a certain value.

While this is straightforward to compare if the array contains numeric values, the same approach does not work with string arrays.

```py
num_array = np.array([2, 2, 3])
string_array = np.array(['a', 'a', 'b'])

num_array == 2 # returns array(['True', 'True', 'False'])
string_array == 'a' # returns False
```

Expected result for

```
string_array == 'a' # array(['True', 'True', 'False'])
```

Comment: Right now, the desired result is obtained by 
[val == 'a' for val in string_array]

Is this the best approach?

Comment: What version of NumPy are you using? I get the expected result using the same code with NumPy 1.16.2.

Comment: The code is also working as expected for me on NumPy 1.16.4.

Comment: It is working for Numpy 1.15.4 as well.

Comment: I'm using Numpy 1.15.4

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In my code, the string_array was not defined as np.array. Apologies.
The code works as expected!